# A continuous root for $(z-a)(z-b)$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, roots

Consider the function $f(z) = (z-a)(z-b)$ defined on $\Omega = \mathbb{C} - [a,b]$ where $a,b$ are different complex numbers.

How can I show that it has a continuous square root on $\Omega$?

In a previous part of this question I showed that this function **doesn't** have a continuous logarithm. In showing this I reasoned that for any real number $\alpha$, $arg_{\alpha}$, the inverse of $exp$ restricted to the set $S_\alpha = \{x + iy : y \in [\alpha, \alpha +2 \pi)\}$, cannot possibly be continuous on $\Omega$ because the image of $f$ must contain some spiral (in any open set actually), and hence points with any argument between $0$ and $2\pi$.

However if the above is correct I have no hope in finding a branch for the square root to be continuous in. Can you assist me with these questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Möbius transformation

$$T \colon z \mapsto \frac{z-a}{z-b}$$

maps $(\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}) \setminus [a,b]$ biholomorphically to $U := \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. On $U$, we have two branches of the square root, each of which we can use to define $\sqrt{T(z)}$. Then

$$g \colon z \mapsto (z-b)\cdot \sqrt{T(z)}$$

is a holomorphic square root of $f$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [a,b]$. (The other is $-g$ of course.)

Comment: Can we generalize this argument to distinct $n$ complex numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$?

Comment: @M.AlessandroFerrari Yes. If $n = 2m$ is even, use this argument to obtain a square root $g_k$ of $(z - a_{2k-1})\cdot(z - a_{2k})$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [a_{2k-1}, a_{2k}]$, and multiply them. The product $g(z) = \prod_{k = 1}^m g_k(z)$ is a holomorphic square root of $\prod_{j = 1}^n (z - a_j)$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \bigcup_{k = 1}^m [a_{2k-1}, a_{2k}]$. If $n$ is odd, $n = 2m+1$, we additionally need a branch cut connecting $a_n$ and $\infty$ and a square root of $z - a_n$ on the complement of that cut.